# How to write double Natural Join in SQL?

Tags: join, relational-theory

> Let be the following database :
>
> - Product(Constructor, Model, Type)
> - PC(Model, Speed, RAM, HD, CD, Price)
> - Laptop(Model, Speed, RAM, HD, Screen, Price)
> - Printer(Model, Color, Type, Price)
>
> Who are the constructors giving printers and PC ?

I think that the answer in relational algebra is :

Π<sub>Constructor</sub>(Product ⋈  Laptop ⋈  Printer)

Yet I don't know how to write it in SQL, would it be :

```
SELECT Constructor
FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Laptop NATURAL JOIN Printer;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why natural join? Why not just be explicit with your join predicates? With SQL, it's always better to be explicit, what happens if the optimizer picks the wrong column in your example?

Comment: your right, I should have done what Vérace did and explicitly write `JOIN PC ON PC.Model = Product.Model` and `JOIN Printer ON Printer.Model = Product.Model`. But this was not what I preconceived in relational algebra in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear - does the 'Type' field
specify 'PC', 'Laptop' or 'Printer' - if so, it's relatively
easy - no need to join at all - just

```
SELECT * -- or whatever
FROM Product
WHERE Type = 'PC' OR Type = 'Printer'
```

If 'Type' is not the above, then it's trickier, but
not too difficult. BTW, 'Type' is a `keyword` in some
RDBMS products - I'd advise changing it to 'p_Type' or
similar.

To solve this, I did the following (SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44bd19/1/0)):

I didn't put in [referential constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) - I leave that as an
exercise for yourself :-) (especially since you haven't provided
your particular RDBMS). I also excluded the non-joining fields
(less typing for me :-) )

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
  Constructor INT NOT NULL, 
  Model VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
  Type VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PC
(
  Model VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Laptop
(
  Model VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Printer
(
  Model VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Product VALUES( 1, 'm_1', 't_1');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES( 2, 'm_2', 't_1');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES( 3, 'm_3', 't_2');
INSERT INTO Product VALUES( 4, 'm_4', 't_3');

INSERT INTO PC VALUES('m_1');
INSERT INTO PC VALUES('m_2');

INSERT INTO Laptop VALUES ( 'm_3');

INSERT INTO Printer VALUES ('m_4');
```

The query:

```
SELECT * -- or whatever
FROM Product
  JOIN PC ON PC.Model = Product.Model
UNION
SELECT * -- or whatever
FROM Product
  JOIN Printer ON Printer.Model = Product.Model
```

Result:

```
Constructor Model   Type    Model
1   m_1 t_1 m_1
2   m_2 t_1 m_2
4   m_4 t_3 m_4
```

Et voilà - the correct result - unless I've misunderstood you?

Comment: I htink the fist sql query you give is false as far as we want the constructors giving printers **and** PC

Answer (score 0):

For getting the right results you can do this:

```
SELECT Constructor
FROM Product as p1
where p1.Type="pc"
INTERSECT
SELECT Constructor
FROM Product as p2
WHERE p2.Type="Printer";
```

Hopefully that will help you get your question solved.

Comment: can you explain why this would be better?